# How to access the uploaded extra data inside test script in AWS Device Farm?

Tags: appium, aws-device-farm

I'm using Java-Appium-TestNG. I've uploaded a Excel file `Testdata.xlsx` containing my test data (using "Add Extra data" option). **Which path** I should mention inside the test script to access the `TestData.xlsx`?

Answer (score 0):

Note: Extra data should be uploaded in form of a zip file. So in your case the excel file should be placed inside a zip file first.

1. For Android, the extra data is extracted to the SD Card of the device.
2. For iOS, the extra data is extracted to the application data folder under .../aapt/data

A sample path on iOS would look like this:
private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/64F3793F-5AFC-4C12-8BF4-XXXXXXXXXXXX/MySampleApp.app/aatp/data

Hope that helps.